# Are strings in pandas.Series always smaller than 0?

Tags: python, pandas

When I evaluate the following snippet of code I get the value `True`

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': ['assa', '100', 'AJSAND']})
(df < 0).all()
```

Is it always the case that strings evaluate to less than zero in a Pandas DataFrame?

However, the following results in an error

```
's' < 0
```

Comment: well `df > 0` will also evaluate to `True` but `df==0` evaluates to `False`, unclear what the rationale is for this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you check the source code of pandas you can find the following lines under **_comp_method_FRAME** method. You can find a complete explanation [here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/4537). In summary, it is more about a way to compare every kind of types without resulting in an exception.

```
def _comp_method_FRAME(cls, func, special):
    str_rep = _get_opstr(func, cls)
    op_name = _get_op_name(func, special)

    @Appender('Wrapper for comparison method {name}'.format(name=op_name))
    def f(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, ABCDataFrame):
            # Another DataFrame
            if not self._indexed_same(other):
                raise ValueError('Can only compare identically-labeled '
                                 'DataFrame objects')
            return self._compare_frame(other, func, str_rep)

        elif isinstance(other, ABCSeries):
            return _combine_series_frame(self, other, func,
                                         fill_value=None, axis=None,
                                         level=None, try_cast=False)
        else:

            # straight boolean comparisons we want to allow all columns
            # (regardless of dtype to pass thru) See #4537 for discussion.
            res = self._combine_const(other, func,
                                      errors='ignore',
                                      try_cast=False)
            return res.fillna(True).astype(bool)

    f.__name__ = op_name

    return f
```

So basically the dataframe is first filled with NaNs which are later removed with the true boolean!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The full explanation in the link you gave made it clear "_the comparisons return True by default (when the comparisons fail, eg fillna(True))_".